# Apply condition to sum

Tags: simplifying-expressions, summation, rule

I have this simple question, given the following sum: `Sum[A[i][j][k],{j,0,10},{k,0,10},{i,0,5}]`

I would like to apply the condition

$ A[i][j][k]=A[i][k][j] $

How can i do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe something like `Sum[If[j == k, A[i][j][k], 2 A[i][j][k]], {j, 0, 10}, {k, j, 10}, {i, 0, 5}]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a [conditional pattern](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Condition.html):

```
Sum[A[i][j][k], {j, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {i, 0, 5}] /.
  A[i_][j_][k_] /; j > k -> A[i][k][j]

(*    A[0][0][0] + 2 A[0][0][1] + 2 A[0][0][2] + ...
      ... + A[5][9][9] + 2 A[5][9][10] + A[5][10][10]    *)
```

Using explicit construction:

```
Sum[A[i][Min[j, k]][Max[j, k]], {j, 0, 10}, {k, 0, 10}, {i, 0, 5}]

(*    same as above    *)
```